# Can NSUserDefaults be Initialized Just Once for the Whole Class

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I need to save the data to NSUserDefaults several times in different methods in the same class, and each time I need to initialize it the following way:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Is it possible to initialize it just once?

For example, declare it as property, and then initialize them in -(void)viewDidLoad in UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>There is no need as that is a *singleton pattern* so only one instance is maintained automatically by `NSUserDefaults`.</strike>

Update after comments from @NikolaiRuhe (many thanks):

There is no need as `NSUserDefaults` provides a default instance that can be used for most purposes, which is exposed by the `sharedUserDefaults` class method that you call.  It's not technically a *singleton* as you are not forced to use this default instance.  However if you always use `sharedUserDefaults` then only one instance will ever be created.

If you are interested in saving typing then create methods in your classes to perform the loading and saving to/from `NSUserDefaults`; for example:

```
- (void)loadConfig
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults sharedUserDefaults];
    _someObjectProperty = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"someProperty"];
    _someIntProperty = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"anotherProperty"];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but you can save lines of code initializing them just once, can't you?

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas Not really no.  You can write a convenience method for your class that automatically saves every property and then calling that method will save lines and reduce mistakes.

Comment: Nitpicking: It's not an actual *singleton*, but the framework exposes a shared "default" instance that is good for most cases. You can create more instances for specific use cases, though.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe That is true; you are not forced to use the singleton, so I guess it's not technically a singleton pattern?  Not sure TBH.

Comment: In a true singleton, as defined by the GOF book, the class makes it impossible to create more than one instance. In Cocoa, it is more common to expose a shared instance but not prevent creation of additional instances. `NSUserDefaults` is more like that—with the difference that you sometimes **have to** create several instances (when accessing other domains or whatever).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Good to know.  I will update.